# SDl Web 8: Could not load type 'DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.IProvider' from assembly 'DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts

Tags: web8

We are upgrading to SDL web 8. while configuring our .net solution, I am facing the following issue.
While creating the Kernel using kernel.UseDD4T() method of DD4T.DI.Ninject.dll (2.1.0) I am getting the following error:
Could not load type 'DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts.Providers.IProvider' from assembly 'DD4T.ContentModel.Contracts

It may be due the mismatch in the dll version in my reference and bind folder. I have double checked it and they are the same.

Is there anything else I am missing.
Appreciate your help

Srikant

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue for the above issue.
there is one method UseDD4T in the DD4T.DI.Ninject dll which read the DD4T dll's form the the solution bin folder. there I had both DD4T.SDLTridion2013 and DD4T.SDLWeb8 dll. it was picking up the 2013 dll and tried to compare with the 2.1.0 version of DD4T dlls which are actually updated for SDLWeb8 and hence the mismatch.

Even though I had correct reference and correct dll in my bin, I was getting the error.

Once I removed the 2013 dll from bin. I was not getting the error.

Srikaknt